# How to use wget with Tor when Tor is censored?

Tags: debian, command-line, wget, tor

I know how to use Tor Browser, and when I connected the Tor Network via Tor Browser, the command

```
curl --socks5-hostname localhost:9150 -O https://dist.torproject.org/tor-0.4.7.10.tar.gz
```

works well, but I failed to use `wget` with Tor. I searched the Internet, but found no tutorial about this when Tor is censored.

Now my questions are

1. Can I connect the Tor Network via CLI when Tor is censored?  In my experience, the only effective bridge is Snowflake, others are not as effective as Snowflake even if sometimes they also work.
2. If I connected the Tor Network via Tor Browser, how to make commands such as `wget` go through the Tor Network?

Now I have connected the Tor Network using the file`snowflake-client` from Tor Browser and modified `torrc` file from Snowflake source code. So far it works well.

Comment: [This question at SuperUser.SE](https://superuser.com/q/404732/784449) might be helpful to you.

Comment: @telcoM It does not discuss the situation when Tor is censored.

Answer (score 0):

So... you "know how to use Tor Browser" when Tor is censored, so presumably you already have a Tor Bridge address you can use. [The link I posted in the comments](https://superuser.com/q/404732/784449) was about using `torify`/`torsocks` to enable use of Tor with commands like `wget`, but your comment indicates that is not what your problem is.

Then, perhaps you are really asking "how to configure a non-browser Tor to use a bridge?" The answer for that is: configure the bridge address in your `torrc` file, which is often located at `/etc/tor/`.

From `man tor`:

> `UseBridges 0|1`
>
> When set, Tor will fetch descriptors for each bridge listed in the
> "Bridge" config lines, and use these relays as both entry guards and
> directory guards. (Default: 0)
>
> `Bridge [transport] IP:ORPort [fingerprint]`
>
> When set along with UseBridges, instructs Tor to use the relay at
> "IP:ORPort" as a "bridge" relaying into the Tor network. If
> "fingerprint" is provided (using the same format as for DirAuthority),
> we will verify that the relay running at that location has the right
> fingerprint. We also use fingerprint to look up the bridge descriptor
> at the bridge authority, if it’s provided and if
> UpdateBridgesFromAuthority is set too.
>
> If "transport" is provided, it must match a ClientTransportPlugin line.
> We then use that pluggable transport’s proxy to transfer data to the
> bridge, rather than connecting to the bridge directly. Some transports
> use a transport-specific method to work out the remote address to
> connect to. These transports typically ignore the "IP:ORPort" specified
> in the bridge line.
>
> Tor passes any "key=val" settings to the pluggable transport proxy as
> per-connection arguments when connecting to the bridge. Consult the
> documentation of the pluggable transport for details of what arguments
> it supports.

If this is not the answer you are looking for, then please describe your failure with using Tor with `wget` in more detail, so we can better understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: The Tor Browser apparently has some bridges configured by default, and you can configure more if necessary. If the Tor Browser works for you with a particular bridge, then that bridge should work added in `torrc` too. If you had to add a bridge to the Tor Browser configuration to make it work, then you definitely have to add it into `torrc` too to successfully use utilities like `wget` with Tor. Note that in man pages and the like, square brackets often mean "this parameter is optional" and should not actually be typed in. So, a minimalist Bridge entry would be just `Bridge 1.2.3.4:5678`.

Comment: So you are using the `snowflake` transport then. See [this question at AskUbuntu.SE](https://askubuntu.com/q/1406561/769591). In short, you need to make sure the `snowflake` `ClientTransportPlugin` is available: install it as a package if you can, or build it from source if you must.

Comment: Unfortunately this method also failed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a DNS and IPv6 issue, not censorship related. It looks `torsocks` does not work when a remote name resolves to an IPv6 address, instead using the SOCKS5 proxy directly allows for remote name resolution, compared to `torsocks`, which uses `LD_PRELOAD` to patch many libc networking functions, including resolution functions. I also see you're not using `curl` with Tor correctly, as using `--socks5` will resolve names locally, leaking DNS requests, you should use either `--socks5-hostname host:port` or `--proxy socks5h://host:port`, or even better stick with Tor Browser.

In other words, `torsocks wget https://example.com` first resolves `example.com` through the Tor network, using a SOCKS5 extension, then connects to the resolved address using the SOCKS5 proxy, `AAAA` resolution is likely the problem here. `curl --socks5 localhost:9150 https://example.com` first resolves `example.com` locally, then connects to the resolved address using the SOCKS5 proxy.